# How to build libpng using mingw

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, libpng

I cannot find on Google any easy way to do this . I try [this](http://my.opera.com/hearton965/blog/2011/08/04/building-zlib-libpng-with-mingw) but `make` says "no target found an no makefile found. Stop". First I did was go into the directory of `lpng162/scripts`  where I can found makefile for gcc but I am new to this `makefile`s and I don't have vstudio to build it easily. Please help. I cannot get it to work. I'm assuming this question to solved my other problems in linking this `libpng16.lib` into my .dll file. This is the only solution I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyways, I figured out how to do this makefile. I just go to lpng16/scripts and I found many makefiles there with a file extension. I choose the gcc because that's only familiar to me. I removed the name extension and put it in the directory where I can find the headers and source files then make. I don't know why they don't include this instruction in the manual or its just difficult to find it there. (just noob question)